# How can I reset the password to my Wattbox WB-700-IPV-12?

Tags: power-distribution-unit, wattbox

I have a open box Wattbox WB-700-IPV-12 I purchased. I would like to reset the password to the web interface. The manual says nothing of how to reset the password. I tried the default of `wattbox` for the username and password, and that didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To reset the master password, you should find a sticker on the underside of the device which has the "MASTER PASSWORD", it's labeled as such.

To use this sticker, go to the secret service page on the device,

```
http://wattboxip/password.cgi
```

Log in with the username "admin" and the above password.